# How to get distinct count of a field and sum a field inside a list which has to be grouped by some fields in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to find the unique name count, and summation of a field value inside a list

Below is my POJO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Orders {
   private String dealId;
   private String fieldId;
   private String accountName;
   private List<Demands> demands;   //Demands contains multiple fields inside it, but I just need 
                                    //the 'amount' value mainly which is a BigDecimal.
}
```

```
List of Orders(ordersList) :

DealId  | FieldId  |  AccountName  |  Demand  |
1       |  11      |  ABC          |  100,100 |
1       |  11      |  ABC          |  200     |
1       |  11      |  PQR          |  300,100 |
1       |  12      |  ABC          |  100     |
2       |  21      |  ABC          |  200     |
2       |  21      |  PQR          |  300,500 |
2       |  21      |  XYZ          |  100     |
2       |  22      |  ABC          |  200,100 |
2       |  22      |  ABC          |  300     |

End Result :

DealId  |  FieldId  | AccountNameCount   |  DemandSum  |
1       |  11       |  2                 |   800       |
1       |  12       |  1                 |   100       | 
2       |  21       |  3                 |   1100      |
2       |  22       |  1                 |   600       |
```

I need to take the end result in some POJO or collection in this format, where

**AccountNameCount**  is the count of unique account names for a particular FieldId for a deal.
**DemandSum** is the summation of the demand value for the particular FieldId under a DealId.

**Note:** Demand is a List inside the Orders model, so it may have multiple values, all those values for a particular FieldId under a DealId should be added.

**For example :** for DealId 1, with FieldId 11, there are 2 unique accountNames, and adding all demand values under that fieldid, and dealId = 800

I am trying this using Java 8 streams, have been able to group the list by dealId, and then the fieldId, but I am not sure how to calculate the unique account name on fieldId level, and the demand value summation, without affecting performance.

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Orders>>> map = ordersList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Orders::getDealId, Collectors.groupingBy(Orders::getFieldId)));
```

The Collectors.reducing option is available to add inside the stream to add demands value, but as the Demands is a list inside Orders, doesnt apply here.

```
Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Demands::getAmount, BigDecimal::add);
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's start with grouping by `dealId` and `fieldId`

After that what we need is `accountName` distinct count and sum of `demands`, but those are available in List, which is inside `Map`
In order to generate stream on map we will use [entrySet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--),

This will gives us [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)<dealId, Map<fieldIs, List>>

To access key, value from Map.Entry we use methods [getKey](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getKey--) and [getValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue--)

```
// group by dealId and fieldId
Map<String, Map<String, List<Orders>>> map = ordersList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Orders::getDealId, Collectors.groupingBy(Orders::getFieldId)));

List<OrdersSummary> result = map
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(Test::getOrdersSummaries)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(result);

  private static List<OrdersSummary> getOrdersSummaries(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<Orders>>> entry) {
    return entry.getValue()
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(e2 -> toOrdersSummary(entry.getKey(), e2))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  private static OrdersSummary toOrdersSummary(String dealId, Map.Entry<String, List<Orders>> entry){
    long accountNameCount= entry.getValue().stream().map(Orders::getAccountName).distinct().count();
    BigDecimal demandSum = entry.getValue().stream().map(Orders::getDemands)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
    return new OrdersSummary(dealId, entry.getKey(), accountNameCount, demandSum);
  }
```

Full code [Demo](https://www.online-java.com/ok1wprSYOg)

Answer (score 1):

Although you can get result by java 8 stream API (maybe unreadable a bit).
but there are another collector([teeing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)) provided after java 12+ that helps you to write this in more readable way.

```
public static Collector teeing​ (Collector downstream1, 
                            Collector downstream2, 
                            BiFunction merger);
```

solution: you need to create some helper objects such as `Detail`, `Result`

```
orders.stream()
      .collect(groupingBy(order -> Arrays.asList(order.getDealId(), order.getFieldId()),
        teeing(  
                 // unique account names for each group
                 mapping(Orders::getAccountName, Collectors.toSet()),
                 // sum all demands amount for each group
                  collectingAndThen(mapping(Orders::getDemands, Collectors.toList()),
                            demands -> demands.stream()
                                  .flatMap(List::stream)
                                  .map(Demands::getAmount)
                                  .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add)),
                  // create an object by previous results
                 (names, demandSum) -> new Detail(names.size(), demandSum) 
                    )
            )).entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new Result(
                    entry.getKey().get(0),
                    entry.getKey().get(1),
                    entry.getValue().getCountByAccountName(),
                    entry.getValue().getDemandSum()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
    return orderList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> Arrays.asList(o.dealId, o.fieldId)))
            .entrySet().stream().map(e -> {
                var stats = new OrderStats();
                stats.dealId = e.getKey().get(0);
                stats.fieldId = e.getKey().get(1);
                stats.accountNameCount = e.getValue().stream()
                        .map(o -> o.accountName)
                        .distinct()
                        .count();
                stats.demandSum = e.getValue().stream()
                        .flatMap(o -> o.demands.stream())
                        .map(d -> d.amount)
                        .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
                return stats;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I use a `List` as key to avoid unnecessary nesting in the grouping `Map`. This works because `List` implements content-based equality.